# Does HCL OneTest Data maintain any log file with the information that helps user to troubleshoot?

Tags: containers, logfile

When the HCL OneTest Data pod container goes down, then does the application maintain the information of each event in the log files? Where can a user find these log files?

Answer (score 0):

When the execution of the map of HCL OneTest Data fails to generate the test data, then you can find detailed information about the failure in the audit log file. For more information about the audit log files you can refer, https://help.hcltechsw.com/onetest/hclonetestserver/10.1.2/com.hcl.test.otd.help.doc/topics/c_help_map_audit_overview.html